# Cakephp Specific controller throwing 404 error

Tags: php, cakephp

I have run into a very strange and confusing problem.
I have been working on a project for about a month now, and everything has been working fine.
I have a production station and a live server, and I use gitHub to sync between them. Suddenly today, my Objects controller started throwing 404 errors, on the server. On the production station everything works fine.

All my other controllers work, so I know its not a rewrite problem.

Has anyone experienced anything like this??

EDIT:
The url I am using to access the controller is /Objects/[function name]

Comment: Check error.log, show the URL you access, show your routing, show the controller code?

Comment: @burzum I didnt post the controller code because it is vary large, and because everything works on the production station I do not believe it is a problem with the controller. I have edited my question with the url I am using